# centering the right does not work

Tags: jquery, css

I am trying to animate my box to left, top, right and bottom and of course to be centered; but right and bottom does not work! Am I doing anything wrong?

```
$mainMenu.animate({         
    right: 0,
    top: (docHeight / 2) - 100,
    bottom: (docHeight / 2) + 100

}, 500);
```

Thanks

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/kbJCc/20/)

Comment: My apologies. I didn't see it :)

Comment: Hmm, looks like the two properties, `left` and `right` are conflicting. When you do `right: 0`, you have simultaneously `left: 0` and `right: 0` for example.

Comment: Maybe! But I dont think so, if thats the case right of the bat, none of them is 0 and still right and bottom do not work!

Comment: right off the bat, `left: (docWidth / 2) - 100`, which is not possible in conjuction with `right: 0`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Working jsfiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/gLumR/).

You need to send it to the bottom using `top`, and send it to the right using `left` (minus the DIV `height` or `width`). Otherwise `top` still equals zero at the bottom and `left` still equals zero on right, if that makes sense:

```
 $('#link1 a').click(function() {
        console.log('docHeight/2',docHeight/2)
        $mainMenu.animate({
            top: (docHeight / 2) - 100,  
             bottom: (docHeight / 2) + 100,
            left: 0           
        }, 500);
    });

    $('#link2 a').click(function() {
        $mainMenu.animate({
            top: 0,
            right: (docWidth / 2) + 100,
            left: (docWidth / 2) - 100
        }, 500);
    });

    $('#link3 a').click(function() {
        $mainMenu.animate({         
            left: (docWidth - $mainMenu.width()),
            top: (docHeight / 2) - 100,
            bottom: (docHeight / 2) + 100

        }, 500);
    });

    $('#link4 a').click(function() {
        $mainMenu.animate({           
            top: (docHeight - $mainMenu.height()),
            right: (docWidth / 2) + 100,
            left: (docWidth / 2) - 100
        }, 500);
    });
```